# PHP: What is the pattern to find numbers-dashed sub-strings and replace after modification?

Tags: php, regex, substring, preg-match-all

I have strings with **numbers-dashes** sub-strings. I want to find these sub-strings and replace them after some modifications.

For example, the string is like:

- *This is the string number **123-45-6789-0** which contains **12-34567**.*

Now I want to find sub-strings of numbers-dashes (**123-45-6789-0** and **12-34567**) and replace them with the modified sub-strings. For example the final string would be like this:

- *This is the modified string number **0-6789-45-123** which contains **34567-12**.*

I have already tried `preg_match_all(string $pattern, string $subject, array &$matches)` with:

- `$pattern = '/-*\d+-*/';`

but it gives me an array of numbers each one with a dash, like this:

- `$matches = [123-, 45-, 6789-, 0, 12-, 34567]`

whereas, I want an array of two sub-strings, like this:

- `$matches = [0 => 123-45-6789-0, 1 => 12-34567]`

in order to do modifications and replacements (using `str_replace()`), separately.

Which pattern and methods should I use for these purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `$pattern = '/\d+(?:-\d+)*/'`, you will need `preg_replace_callback` though.

Comment: You can test your pattern here:  https://regex101.com/

Comment: I don't understand: the example you give is just a string reverse, so: can you be a bit more detailed in what you actually want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `\d+(?:-\d+)+` regex with a preg_replace_callback` function:

```
$str = 'This is the string number 123-45-6789-0 which contains 12-34567.';
echo preg_replace_callback('~\d+(?:-\d+)+~', function($m) { 
    return implode('-', array_reverse(explode('-', $m[0]))); }
,$str);
// => This is the string number 0-6789-45-123 which contains 34567-12.
```

See [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/33tjk) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c69xyI/1).

The `\d+(?:-\d+)+` pattern matches

- `\d+`  - 1+ digits
- `(?:-\d+)+` - 1 or more occurrences of `-` and 1+ digits sequences.

`$m` is a match array, `$m[0]` holds the match value. With `explode`, the string is split with `-`, then the array is reversed, and then joined back with `implode`.

Comment: This was the answer, thank you so much, it helps me a lot.